# How do I maintain image size when printing using a PHP while loop with CSS page breaks?

Tags: php, css, printing

I need to print drawings with "position: absolute" DIVs which contain the drawing dimensions being pulled out of my database for each record. The images are in a WHILE loop with a page break after each record/image. I have CSS for screen media and CSS for print media. When I look at a print preview, with each successive page, the image gets smaller and my position: absolute DIVS get out of alignment with the image. How can I maintain the page size with each record loop and page break?

I though I had solved the position:absolute DIV printing alignment problem using the CSS media print style. It works until the images start getting smaller as the PHP loop creates more pages.

Comment: Normally the images will NOT get smaller when more pages are generated, it must be due to something strange in your code. (**Hence, please post your code**)

Comment: Please share a set of minimal HTML+CSS code that is **just enough** to demonstrate your problem. That means to **trim down** your code until there is **only the required elements**, and nothing else, to show the issue. Then share it here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.